# Get the count of a many to many relationship in two levels in the same query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am getting the list of friends of a particular user using this query.

```sql
SELECT users.* from users 
      inner join friends ON user_id = id OR user_id2 = id
      WHERE (user_id = 33 OR user_id2 = 33) AND id != 33

    GROUP BY user_id, user_id2, id
```

Now i want to include the number of friends each user have in the same query

How can i do that?

This seems like a duplicate but i couldn't apply other answers to my problem. Help is highly appreciated.

This is the schema of the database

```
create table if not exists users (
      id serial primary key,
      phone_number text,
      cin text,
      name text,
      positive_date timestamp,
      address text,
      created_at timestamp default now()
    );

create table if not exists friends (
      user_id integer not null references users,
      user_id2 integer not null references users,
      created_at timestamp default now(),
      distance integer
    );
```

And a couple of insert statements to try things out

```sql
INSERT INTO users (id, phone_number, cin, name, positive_date, address, created_at) VALUES (20, '0306200503', 'k26jx2dx', 'Mathis Gerard', NULL, '2222 Dubois de Provence Suite 117', '2020-03-30 08:31:42.674733');
INSERT INTO users (id, phone_number, cin, name, positive_date, address, created_at) VALUES (21, '0306200503', 'k26jx2dx', 'Mathis Gerard', NULL, '2222 Dubois de Provence Suite 117', '2020-03-30 08:31:42.674733');

INSERT INTO friends (user_id, user_id2, created_at, distance) VALUES (20, 21, '2020-06-05 17:23:00.635', 2);
```

And here is an image explaining things in more details: 
[image]

The result of the query `Get friends of user 1 and their number of friends` would return the following:

```
- 2: id, name ... + count = 2
- 3: id, name ... + count = 1
```

Comment: Make it easy to assist you: [mcve], https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: @jarlh i added the db schema. Is it enough?

Comment: added insert statements as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want the number of friends, how about a subquery:

```
select u.*,
       (select count(*)
        from friends f
        where u.id in (f.user_id, f.user_id2)
       )
from users u
where id = 33;
```

I would be surprised if someone could befriend themselves.  If so, you can add `f.user_id <> f.user_id2` in the subquery.